# how make query is null on bookshelf

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js

I'm using the Bookshelf.js ORM and I need be able to query 'parent_id is null' but I'm having having some issues.

here is a samples code snippet that I'm using.

```
    const Model = require('../Models/Message') 
    const result = await new Model().query('parent_id', 'is null').fetchAll();
```

The above code just returns a error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the querybuilder:

```
const result = await new Model().query((queryBuilder) => {
  queryBuilder.whereNull('parent_id');
}).fetchAll();
```

Or simply:

```
const result = await new Model()
  .where('parent_id', 'is', null)
  .fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const Model = require('../Models/Message') 
const result = await new Model().query((qb) => {
        qb.where('parent_id', null)
    })
    .fetchAll()
```